# Open up a form only once by finding out if a class of form is already open

Tags: vb.net

I have a menulist with some menuitems that opening a form that accepts a parameter. At the moment, when it opens the form it will create another form, rather than focusing on the form if its already open.

I've seen plenty of C# examples but have difficulty converting them.

I've tried this code, but I think its not working because allthough the menu form is a mdiContainer form, the form it opens isnt a child.  I've shown this as its what I want to find, i.e. is a specific CLASS of form open.

```
    For Each child In Me.MdiChildren
        If TypeOf child Is frmCustomerPurchaseOrders Then
            child.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
            child.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

    Dim myForm As New frmCustomerPurchaseOrders("NotFullyInvoiced")
    myForm.Show()
```

I have looked at My.Application.OpenForms which does pick up the form text, but as the form text changes when It opens, its hard to match by form name.  Is there a way of checking if a particular Class of form is already open?

```
        For Each f As Form In My.Application.OpenForms
            MessageBox.Show(f.Text)
        Next
```

However, if I'm going along the wrong path in doing this please let me know!  Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the exact same thing with OpenForms, that your example code is doing with MdiChildren; just check the type of each Form, `f`, in the loop:

```
For Each f As Form In My.Application.OpenForms
    If TypeOf f Is frmCustomerPurchaseOrders Then
        ' ... do something in here with "f" ...
    End If
Next
```